# How to remove question mark appearing in right side of the Menu bar which is sharepoint help window in sharepoint website

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2010

This is a simple question as i do not have much exposure in sharepoint 
My query is:
A question mark appearing in the right side of the menu bar / navigation bar of my sharepoint website which is basically is for opening help window of sharepoint

here is the link of the image where you can understand better

http://postimg.org/image/wubglmrj3/[1](http://postimg.org/image/wubglmrj3/)

Comment: This is question mark for `Help`..

Comment: Yes i want to make it visible false
How to do it ?

Comment: Plz show me ur user interface code..

Comment: I have posted the image link:

Comment: here is the image : http://postimg.org/image/wubglmrj3/1

Comment: oho i know you have posted image button but we need to hide that image from ur coding side.Are you using any master page.If yes then try to find that image control in the master page.

Comment: check globally search for `help` or something like that in the program.

Comment: No its not comming from masterpage. I think it can be removed from sharepoint designer tool. but i have little knowledge to do so . So any sharepoint expert can help me

Answer (score 1):

you can try this approach and see if it provides the expected behaviour.

add this to an existing css file or just inject it into the master page along with a style tag, under the head section

```
.s4-help {
    display: none !important;
}
```